# How to Integrate Google Cloud Services With Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, cloud, text-to-speech

I have been wondering if it is possible to integrate Google Cloud Services such as Cloud Text-to-Speech in Flutter. The lack of documentation makes me wonder if there's some workaround or something because I can't find a way to integrate.

As you can see in the documentation, there are only samples for different languages, no presence for Flutter:
https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/samples/tts-synthesize-text

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LMAd.png)

Any suggestions? Will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

GCP TtS is available also by REST API calls, as any other GCP service. So you can write Dartcode to perform an HTTP POST request to send text or audio.

BTW you have to consider how to authenticate to TtS, and there are different options, some of them:

1. your users need to be authenticated in your GCP organization by your mobile app, and they also need to have the permissions to invoke that service. Then your app can invoke TtS using HTTP POST and impersonating the user.
2. your mobile app authenticate the users without a GCP or Firebase identity. In that case you need a backend layer (might be a REST service or a simple Cloud function) acting as a proxy between your mobile app and TtS. Your app calls your backend, the backend authenticates to TtS using a service account (GPC identity), then the backend invokes TtS and sends back the result to your mobile app.